# Фильтрация (перебор значений в select)

Tags: javascript

У меня есть DATA, в которой содержаться данные, на сайте есть фильтрация, сделана через select, данные этого select'a это массив значений. То есть если в select'е выбрать value, который есть в DATA этот товар должен отображаться. Сейчас возникает ошибка при попытке фильтрации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, если в фильтре выбрано "A", должен отображаться только первый и второй товар.

Вот что у меня есть:

```js
const filters = document.querySelector("#filters");

filters.addEventListener("input", filterGoods);

function filterGoods() {
  const category = filters.querySelector("#category").value;

  outputGoods(DATA.filter((n) => (!category.length || category.filter((s) => n.category.includes(s)).length)));
}

function outputGoods(goods) {
  document.getElementById("goods").innerHTML = goods
    .map(
      (n) => `
      <div class="school-wrapper">
        <div class="school__row">
         <div class="school__col__left">
             <div class="school__logo">
                 <img src="" alt="${n.title}">
                 <div class="school__rating">
                     ${n.rating}
                 </div>
                 <div class="school__reviews">
                     <span>Кол-во отзывов: ${n.reviews}</span>
                 </div>
                   <button class="school__btn"> ${n.category} </button>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="school__col__right">
               <h2 class="school__title">${n.title}</h2>
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>
  `
    )
    .join("");
}

const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Product 1",
    rating: '[ratings id="261"]',
    reviews: '[su_post field="comment_count" post_id="261"]',
    category: ["A", "B", "C"],

  },
  {
      title: "Product 1",
    rating: '[ratings id="261"]',
    reviews: '[su_post field="comment_count" post_id="261"]',
    category: ["A", "B"],
  },
    {
      title: "Product 1",
    rating: '[ratings id="261"]',
    reviews: '[su_post field="comment_count" post_id="261"]',
    category: ["D"],
  },
]
outputGoods(DATA);
```

```html
    <div id="filters">
           <div class="country"><h2>Категория</h2>
            <select id="category">
              <option value="">-- Категория --</option>
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>
              <option value="C">C</option>
              <option value="D">D</option>   
            </select>     
          </div>

      
      <div id="goods"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const filters = document.querySelector("#category");
filters.addEventListener("change", filterGoods);

function filterGoods() {
  const category = filters.value;
  outputGoods(DATA.filter(n => !category.length || n.category.includes(category)));
}

function outputGoods(goods) {
  document.getElementById("goods").innerHTML = goods
    .map(
      (n) => `
      <div class="school-wrapper">
        <div class="school__row">
         <div class="school__col__left">
             <div class="school__logo">
                 <img src="" alt="${n.title}">
                 <div class="school__rating">
                     ${n.rating}
                 </div>
                 <div class="school__reviews">
                     <span>Кол-во отзывов: ${n.reviews}</span>
                 </div>
                   <button class="school__btn"> ${n.category} </button>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="school__col__right">
               <h2 class="school__title">${n.title}</h2>
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>
  `
    )
    .join("");
}

const DATA = [{
    title: "Product 1",
    rating: '[ratings id="261"]',
    reviews: '[su_post field="comment_count" post_id="261"]',
    category: ["A", "B", "C"],

  },
  {
    title: "Product 1",
    rating: '[ratings id="261"]',
    reviews: '[su_post field="comment_count" post_id="261"]',
    category: ["A", "B"],
  },
  {
    title: "Product 1",
    rating: '[ratings id="261"]',
    reviews: '[su_post field="comment_count" post_id="261"]',
    category: ["D"],
  },
];

filterGoods();
```

```html
<div class="country">
  <h2>Категория</h2>
  <select id="category">
    <option value="">-- Категория --</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="goods"></div>
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо!:)